# Having trouble parsing some xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing, namespaces

I am trying to parse some XML that has been put into a column. To simplify, I have put the XML directly into a variable and tried to parse it here.

```
Declare @XMLToParse XML
SELECT @XMLToParse = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atn:Transaction xmlns:atn="http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/cosmos.xsd">
    <name>AIRW0043</name>
    <address>654577</address>
</atn:Transaction>'
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/cosmos.xsd',
    'http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/' as atn)

Select  @XMLToParse.value('data(/atn:Transaction/name)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') namecode
    ,   @XMLToParse.value('data(/atn:Transaction/address[1]','VARCHAR(100)') addresscode
```

I am getting `null` for both values (`namecode` and `addresscode`). I should get the `name` value in `namecode` and the `address` value in `addresscode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was that you're setting default namespace in `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement. That causes all elements without explicit prefix in your XPath/XQuery (f.e `/name` and `/address`) to be considered in the default namespace -while in the actual XML they are in no namespace-.

So in short, simply remove default namespace from your `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement :

```
Declare @XMLToParse XML
SELECT @XMLToParse = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<atn:Transaction xmlns:atn="http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/cosmos.xsd">
    <name>AIRW0043</name>
    <address>654577</address>
</atn:Transaction>'
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/' as atn)

Select  @XMLToParse.value('data(/atn:Transaction/name)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') namecode
    ,   @XMLToParse.value('data(/atn:Transaction/address)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') addresscode
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use 'text()' to get the element value

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.agcs.com/Transaction/' as atn)

Select  @XMLToParse.value('(/atn:Transaction/name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') namecode
    ,   @XMLToParse.value('(/atn:Transaction/address/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') addresscode
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still isn't returning the values from the 'address' and 'name'

Comment: @radar actually that wasn't the problem in this particular case. It still work -or doesn't work- the same way regardless of using `/text()` or not